# highcharts: internet explorer ignores width of my div container

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, highcharts

I'm trying to render a graph with [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and even though it is a wonderful library, I'm having issues with IE (strange... :( ), due to the fact that the library ignores the height that I set in the style attribute of my div container and overflows the expected sizes.

```
<div id="graficoVolumi" style="width: 100%; height: 400px">

</div>
```

I don't have this issue in Firefox or Chrome, in which the graph actually fits the dimensions set in the style attribute.

Has anyone expereinced this issue?

Comment: Which IE version are you facing problem ? As permy knowledge it runs well on all browsers from IE6

Comment: The problem affects just IE9, while in IE8 and IE7 it works as expected, apart for performance that is poorer :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, the way I solve it was to force the width and height of the chart.

By default the width is calculated from the offset width of the containing element.

[HighCharts width Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.width)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with highcharts and IE as well. Curiously enough, this got fixed when I added the HTML5 doctype tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top of my page.